# Codeigniter .htaccess not making my urls correct

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have following .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

I am on localhost with WAMP installed on it. Normally this htaccess work perfectly but this time it isn't I have to mention index.php in my URLs. I have checked mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache. I just want to know what I missed

Comment: show application/config/config.php

Comment: $config['base_url'] = ''; and $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: Alright I fixed the issue by re-installing the wamp, but I am still not able to figure out what was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: may be issue in your config file!

Comment: havbe you changed this line in config?? $config['url_suffix'] = '';

Comment: What should i put in url_suffix ? @ Kunal

Comment: make it just blank ""